# APPSYNC - Possible to use __typename for a sort key using a resolver mapping template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I have a big table and need a sortkey to be able to retrieve all the items.  I want the sortkey to use all the items so I would like to put it on the automatically generated '__typename' field.  This was causing problems and then an AI bot told me I cold use $util.typename in a resolver to map typename to __typename.  Well a day later and a lot of copy/paste of AI generated resolvers has gotten me nothing but a bunch of errors.  So my question is IS THIS EVEN POSSIBLE? if so, how?